# Bootstrap won't work on template

Tags: css, bootstrap, stylesheets

I'm new to EE and I have an issue linking to bootstraps folder. The default_site template (home page) stylesheet link to assets folder works fine, but when I make a new template_group and then a new template the links won't work. Any idea why the default_site template links work, but new template links won't? Here are the links to the bootstrap folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using a relative path for `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">` instead of an absolute.

Your default template works because your index file is on the same directory level as your `assets` folder.

Example:
https://mysite.com/index.php
https://mysite.com/assets/...

However, when you don't use a leading slash in your URL, the path is relative to where you are in the directory structure.

Example:
A link to the file `assets/mystyles.css` from the URL https://mysite.com/subpage would be the same as saying https://mysite.com/subpage/assets/mystlyes.css

Using an absolute path, tells the server you want to go back to the top of the tree to access this path. Thus you would want to use `/assets/mystyles.css`

Example:
A link to the file `/assets/mystyles.css` from the URL https://mysite.com/subpage would be the same as saying https://mysite.com/assets/mystlyes.css

When you use the `{site_url}` variable, an absolute URL is created. Using `{site_url}assets/mystyles.css` would render in the browser as `https://mysite.com/assets/mystyles.css`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, by adding `{site_url}` it worked, but I don't need it for the default_template. Maybe someone knows why?

```
href="{site_url}assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```